# PayPal Forms Next to One Another and CSS Positioning

Tags: css, forms, positioning

I've made a JSFiddle to show what I'm working with:

http://jsfiddle.net/BA6hJ/

```
#rightcolumn {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
```

In the #rightcolumn, everything is floated left, but the PayPal forms appear on top of one another instead of next to one another.  Is there a reason why this is happening?  Something to do with the  tag in general?  Not quite sure.

Also, is there a way to position things side by side in the right column if everything is floated left?

Thank you for any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BA6hJ/2/)

You could use the CSS:

```
form[action='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr']{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

I would tend to recommend replacing the `[action=` selector with a class assigned to the forms for this specific purpose however.

As long as the parent container is wide enough, the forms will display side by side.

Comment: So, just to be specific, I would make a class specifically for these forms?  And then use that class in the html for all of the forms?

What exactly does that inline tag do?  Thank you for your help!

Comment: For the forms you want to display next to each other, edit your code `<form class='inline'..` then change the above CSS to `form.inline{...` the benefit is unline float it's designed for this purpose

Comment: See here for inline-block: http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/

Comment: Sorry to be so naive, but by changing the CSS to "form.inline{...}, do you mean to make a class that is .forminline (I thought you need to start with a period to identify class) and then have the "display:inline-block" code within that?  Would both forms have to have this class attached to them or just the first?

Again, thank you very much as I am still very much in the learning phase!

Answer (score 1):

You should use float on the form it self like this -

```
<form style="float:left" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BA6hJ/1/

Comment: That didn't appear to work...they seem to be still on top of each other unless I'm missing something?

Comment: I see it in one line... you sure theres enough width make it work on the same line?

Comment: try adding this - min-width: 306px; to your support us element

Comment: Yup, sorry, you were right!  Could you explain why I have to float on the form itself in order for the forms to appear side by side?

Comment: A form tags usually break lines[like div and many other elements] but if you define that it 'floats' then it ignore that line breaking. same thing goes ON SW4 answer,when you define 'inline-block' you tell the browser read it as something that suppose to be in the same line